# Как динамичски заполнить QListView

Tags: c++, listview, qt5

В приложении есть QListView с именем listView1, который нужно заполнить из основного кода окна - main.cpp. Но он создан в интерактивном конструкторе Qt Creator. Как к нему можно получить доступ?

Comment: Код покажите, пожалуйста)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, Код пока что чист, я создал виджет QListItem в конструкторе, соответственно он появился в XML коде, а не в C++ файле окна. Как раз мне хочется узнать, как в этом файле получить доступ к нему и создать другие виджеты в нём. В официальной документации пока этого пункта не нашёл.

Comment: `ui->listView1`

Comment: `QListView` напрямую не заполняется. Вместо этого создаётся модель, связывается с `QListView` и уже она заполняется данными (или получает оные откуда-то извне).

Comment: Заполнять можно QListWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему, поменяв QListViewItem на QListWidgetItem

```
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

FMain::FMain(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::FMain)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    auto list=ui->nameOfList;
    new QListWidgetItem(tr("Test"),list);
}
```